# Modifying GitHub Categorization of a Code Repository in my GitHub Account

Tags: git, github, tagging

[image]

I uploaded an ASP.NET application that uses AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC frameworks to my online github.com account using Visual Studio.

It's weird that Github.com automatically categorizes my ASP.NET application with as 'JavaScript'.  How do I get rid the said JavaScript categorization, and add custom categorization?  Or if it's not possible to add custom categorization, how do I just add the C# categorization?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/my-repository-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has a clear answer in GitHub documentation